Given an inconsistent overdeterminate system AX=b where $A\in M_{m×n}(R)$ and $b\in R^m$ with rank A=n. Find the least square approx. solution of AX=b
Suppose $A$ is a real matrix of order $m\times n$ with $m>n,b\in\Bbb R^m$ be such that the over determined system
of linear equations $AX=b$ is inconsistent and $\text{rank} (A)= n.$ Let $W$ be the column space of $A$ and $b_0$ be the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto $W$ ($\Bbb R^m,\Bbb R^n$ are
assumed to be with the standard inner product). Find the least square approximate solution of $AX = b.$
First, I need to be clear of how I'm interpreting the terms in the questions.
I think what they mean by a least square approximate solution is this:

Suppose we have a data about the population in a year or the number of grains produced per year or anything in the form $(t_1,y_1), (t_2,y_2), \cdots, (t_n,y_n)$ where $t_i$'s are the independent variables (i.e it may stand for year, for example).
Now, suppose we feel that the points $(t_1,y_1), (t_2,y_2), \cdots, (t_n,y_n)$ somewhat corresponds to "mostly" a linear relation, i.e say, of the form $y=ct+d$, where the points $(t_1,y_1), (t_2,y_2), \cdots, (t_n,y_n)$ will lie either on the line $y=ct+d$ or will lie "very close" to it. This of course depends upon the parameters $c$ and $d$ which we must determine in order to find the required line which has the least distance from the points,  $(t_1,y_1), (t_2,y_2), \cdots, (t_n,y_n).$ 
More precisely, we want to determine the particular constants $c$ and $d$ such that $E=\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-ct_i-d)^2$ is the minimum. The line $y=ct+d$ corresponding to the choice of $c$ and $d$ so that $E$ is minimum is called the least square line.
The same thing can be done if we choose to have a polynomial instead of a straight line that approximates the data.


By over-determine system I think what they mean is:

A system of linear equations is called an over determined system if, the number of equations provided is more than the number of unknown variables.

Next, $b_0$ is the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto $W$ is specified. So this means, for $b\in W$ we have a unique $b_0\in W$ and $b_0'\in W^{\perp}$ such that $b=b_0+ b_0'.$
Now, the question asks us to find the least approximate solution of $AX=b$ so, I take it they wants us to find a unique $x_0$ as mentioned above.
Here goes my solution:
It is a standard result that if $A\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$ and $y\in \Bbb R^m$ then $!\exists x_0\in \Bbb R^m$ such that $||Ax_0-y||\leq ||Ax-y||,\forall x\in \Bbb R^n$ satisfying, $A^*Ax_0=A^*y.$
Here, $y=b.$
But it is given that, $\text{rank}(A)=n$ so, $\text{rank}(A^*A)=n$ which in turn means, that $A^*A$ is invertible. Hence, $x_0=(A^*A)^{-1}A^*b,$ which is precisely the least square approximate solution of $AX=b.$

I am a bit unsure whether my solution is valid. This is because, the information that, "$b_0$ is the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto $W$" seems unnecessary and there seems to be no use of $W$ as well. Is this really the case? I mean, am I correct? If there is something wrong with my approach, please do point it out.

Since the question was "Find the least square approximate solution of AX=b", your solution which is the standard least squares result is by definition the correct answer. And indeed you do not need to look at $b_0$, neither to derive that solution nor to compute it.
Of course you can use $b_0$ to express the solution as
$x_0=(A^*A)^{-1}A^*b_0,$ if you happen to know what $b_0$ is, but that is not simpler than just using $x_0=(A^*A)^{-1}A^*b.$

So this means my answer along with my method, i.e both are correct, right?(+1 from me)
